# It rains in Gadyukino

Tags: mathematics, probability

It rains in Gadyukino village every other day on average.  Assume the probability of rain on any given day is 50% and independent. A local weather forecaster has the sole duty every day of predicting whether it will rain the following day.  His predictions have a 75% success rate. What quantity of information (in bits) is carried by a single forecast of his?

Comment: In my view, it is reasonable to try interpreting the problem assuming the statement is complete and correct - and the initial statement allowed such an interpretation, including independence of days (otherwise the statement would be incomplete about how the history affects the weather), and also about the quantity (_how much_) of information (see [quantities of information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantities_of_information)).

Answer (score 4):

"How much information" sounds vague. But it has a rock-solid definition, in the grand tradition of Shannon et al.

Assume an independent 1/2 chance of rain every day. Then the weather transmits one bit of information to Gadyukino every day - namely, whether or not it is raining. Say the forecaster can receive $x$ bits of information per day about the future. Then what is the minimum value of $x$ so that in the limit, the forecaster predicts with 75% accuracy?

Consider a time period of $4n$ days for large $n$. There are $2^{4n}$ possible weathers during this period. For any particular forecaster prediction sequence, the number of weather sequences that let the forecaster claim a 75% accuracy rate is $\binom{4n}{\leq n}$, where the notation means the number of ways to choose at most $n$ wrong days out of $4n$ total days.

Stirling's approximation says that $\binom{4n}{\leq n} = 2^{(4\log 4 - 3 \log 3)n}\times poly(n)$. Call this quantity $X$ for ease of typing.

Each forecaster prediction sequence allows $X$ possible weather sequences. There are $2^{4n}$ total weather sequences. Therefore, the forecaster must have at least $2^{4n}/X = 2^{(4 - 4 \log 4 + 3 \log 3)n}$ possible prediction sequences that he might say.

In order to be able to choose from that many prediction sequences, the forecaster must receive at least $\log(\text{that many})=(4 - 4 \log 4 + 3 \log 3)n$ bits for those $4n$ days. **(EDIT: This doesn't account for the fact that the forecaster can change his mind based on whether he's been right so far. My intuition says an information-theoretic bound should still work, I'll think about it.)**

This works out to $\boxed{1-\log 4 + \frac 34 \log 3 \approx 0.43766...}$ bits per day. This is an upper bound on the amount of information the forecaster needs. Does this much information suffice? I don't know. Shannon probably solved this problem when he created information theory, but I'm having trouble finding a reference.

Answer (score 0):

It rains on alternate days on average, which means that:

- If today it's sunny, it's likely that it will rain tomorrow.
- If today it's raining, it's likely that it's sunny tomorrow.

The forecasters peruse the recent weather statistics and discover that 75% of the sunny days were followed by a rainy day. 
So, if today it's sunny, we have a 75% probability of rain tomorrow.
Why we assumed that today it's sunny? Because it says that rains occurs every other day, and if today it's rainy, a 75% chance of rain for tomorrow would conflict with the assumptions.